# ActiveMQ Spring Stomp: how can i change my existing code to create persistent subscription

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, stomp

I have created in my project a notification system which is working. My actual code is:

My client (javascript):

```
let connectWebSocket = () => {
  socket = new SockJS(context.backend + '/myWebSocketEndPoint');
  stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  stompClient.connect({},function (frame) {
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/notification', function(response){
      alert(response);
    });
  });
}
connectWebSocket();
```

Server (Java with Spring)

```
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/myWebSocketEndPoint")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

This is working. Now i want to send to user notification also when they're offline: when they will make login, i'll send (in automatic) them the notifications. I have to do this with activeMQ. I've seen some examples, but don't understand well them.. Someone can indicate me how can i accurate edit my code and realize persistent subscription? Thanks a lot

**EDIT**: I've updated my client-side code:

```
let connectWebSocket = () => {
  let clientId =user.profile.id;
  socket = new SockJS(context.backend + '/myWebSocketEndPoint');
  stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  stompClient.connect({"client-id": clientId},{},function (frame) {
    stompClient.subscribe('/topic/notification', function(response){
      alert(response);
    },{"activemq.subscriptionName": clientId});
  });
}
```

but when a user is offline, if a notification arrive, when he returns online, the notification is not sent him..I suppose I have to change my server side

POM.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.14.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT2:**:
With the right dependency in pom.xml, i have now an error. I have this configuration:

```
@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
   config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic/");
}
```

but when i run my code i see this error:

```
2017/01/24 17:17:15.751 ERROR [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication:839] Application startup failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'stompBrokerRelayMessageHandler'; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: reactor/io/codec/Codec
```

**EDIT3:** this is how i send notification to clients:

```
@Component
public class MenuItemNotificationSender {

@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

@Autowired
public MenuItemNotificationSender(SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate){
    this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
}

public void sendNotification(MenuItemDto menuItem) {
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/notification", menuItem);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is default behaviour for durable subscribers if you use default AMQ config, messages will be persisted, 
if you want to send to user notification also when they're offline you need to use durable suscriptions.

**EDIT**

> Persistent Messaging in STOMP STOMP messages are non-persistent by
>   default. To use persistent messaging add the following STOMP header to
>   all SEND requests: persistent:true. This default is the opposite of
>   that for JMS messages.

To persist sent messages, on js client you need to add header to this method :

```
stompClient.send(destination,  {"persistent":"true" }, body);
```

**UPDATE your MenuItemNotificationSender like this :**

```
public void sendNotification(MenuItemDto menuItem) {
    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("JMSDeliveryMode", 2);
    headers.put("persistent", "true");
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/notification", menuItem, headers);
}
```

take a look

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-make-messages-durable.html

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-durable-queues-and-topics-work.html

to make durable subscriptions with stomp :

```
    stompClient.connect( {"client-id": "my-client-id" },, function ( frame ) {

      console.log( 'Connected: ' + frame );

      stompClient.subscribe( topic, function ( message ) {
        .....
        .....
      }, {"activemq.subscriptionName": "my-client-id"});
   }, function(frame) {
        console.log("Web socket disconnected");
   });
```

**UPDATE**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer{



@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public BrokerService broker() throws Exception {
    final BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    //broker.addConnector("tcp://localhost:61616");
    broker.addConnector("stomp://localhost:61613");
    broker.addConnector("vm://localhost");
    PersistenceAdapter persistenceAdapter = new KahaDBPersistenceAdapter();
    File dir = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "kaha");
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
    persistenceAdapter.setDirectory(dir);
    broker.setPersistenceAdapter(persistenceAdapter);
    broker.setPersistent(true);
    return broker;
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    // if AMQ is running in local not needed to set relayHost & relayPort
    config.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic/")
   .setRelayHost(relayHost)
   .setRelayPort(relayPort)
   // user pwd if needed
   //.setSystemLogin(activeMqLogin)
   //.setSystemPasscode(activeMqPassword)
   ;
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/myWebSocketEndPoint")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

use parent pom

> ```
> <parent>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
>   <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
>   <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
> </parent>
>
>
>
>
>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
>   <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
>   <artifactId>reactor-net</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>io.projectreactor.spring</groupId>
>   <artifactId>reactor-spring-context</artifactId>
> </dependency>
>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>   <artifactId>activemq-kahadb-store</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
>   <artifactId>activemq-stomp</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> <dependency>
>   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
>   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
> </dependency>
> ```