# When using Spring Boot and STOMP, is there a way to make queues not delete messages?

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, stomp

I have an application that uses Java on the backend end, Angular on the frontend, and I'm trying to use STOMP messaging between the two to exchange state data.

What I would like to do is have my services, on startup, publish their states and have that data stay in the queue for any client that later connects to the server.

(edit)

For clarification, I don't mean I want to messages to survive a server reboot. What I want is for certain message queues to retain all messages until the server reboots.

How do I tell Spring Boot's STOMP implementation to not delete the contents of a /queue?

Comment: Generally speaking the term "durable" in messaging has a pre-existing meaning. A "durable" message is one that "will survive a restart." What you're talking about is more like a non-destructive queue where acknowledgements don't actually remove messages. This is an advanced use-case not likely supported by Spring's internal STOMP broker. However, it would be supported by an external broker like ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: It sound like you want a topic with durable subscribers. This is where the publish/subscribe topic will hold each message until all registered subscribers have received it. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41827769/activemq-spring-stomp-how-can-i-change-my-existing-code-to-create-persistent-su) question may help.

Comment: You're right, @JustinBertram, I mistated my question. I'm fixing the question now.

Comment: @HopeyOne, that won't work for clients who haven't subscribed yet. As stated, the requirement is to, "...have that data stay in the queue for any client that later connects to the server."

Comment: @JustinBertram, that's probably a fair assumption given that angular is mentioned. Either way the concept of a queue is send -> consume (i.e. not suitable for the described publish/subscribe scenario).  I would suggest that if a topic with durable subscribers is not suitable, then a messaging solution is probably not the best option.  I'm not sure STOMP or any underlying messaging service supports leaving a message on a topic forever.

Comment: If you are wedded to the STOMP client/server messaging, there is always the request-reply model, whereby the client subscribes to a reply queue and the sets the reply-to for a request it sends to the server. The server would then respond to messages on the request queue with some cached status information (from some non-messaging related data structure) and send it to the reply queue.

Comment: @HopeyOne, as noted in my first comment, ActiveMQ Artemis (which can be integrated with Spring to serve as the STOMP broker) *does* support this kind of use-case via a ["non-destructive" queue](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/last-value-queues.html#forcing-all-consumers-to-be-non-destructive).

Comment: @JustinBertram, indeed, you should post that as the answer.

Comment: @JustinBertram Last-value queue is definitely something that would work in my use cases here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure [ActiveMQ Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/) as an ["external broker"](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#websocket-stomp-handle-broker-relay) and use a ["non-destructive" queue](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/last-value-queues.html#forcing-all-consumers-to-be-non-destructive). When a STOMP client receives and acknowledges a message from a non-destructive queue the broker will *not* remove it. You can define a special "initialization" queue which all clients connect to initially to receive the state data which you care about and then they can connect to whatever other queues they need to complete their normal work.

In this kind of use-case the queue is typically configured as non-destructive *and* as a ["last value" queue](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/last-value-queues.html). This way each client can use its own "last value" and can keep their state data up-to-date without the complication of stale state data on the queue.

I realize your question was asking about how to do this with Spring's built-in broker, but all my research indicates that Spring's simple in-memory broker neither supports last-value queue semantics nor non-destructive queue semantics nor even persistent messages. From what I understand Spring's broker is only meant for the most basic use-cases which is why then enable integration with 3rd party brokers which can support more advanced use-cases (e.g. like yours).

Comment: Ah, but that seems to require adding an external entity to the application. I was hoping for a way to configure the internal broker provided by Spring to have a non-destructive queue.

Comment: I think it answers it only in that it implies that Spring's built in broker doesn't use last-value nor persistent queues. If you can update it to say that clearly then I'd mark it as answered.

Comment: Updated accordingly. Thanks!